How to draw a multi-diagonal lines of three regions in a multi-row and multi-column table
just like the drawing:


here is my code:
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
    \toprule
    \diagbox[dir=SE]{A}{B}{C} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{A} & B     & C     & D \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & A1    & A2    & A3    &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    3600 A &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{x\newline{(W)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{x\newline{}(W)} &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    HXR 50-100 keV &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1\newline{}(W)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1\newline{}(W)} &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    HXR 32-50 keV &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1\newline{}(W)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1\newline{}(W)} &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    HXR 15-25 keV &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    1-8A  &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    1-200A &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    1-800 A &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    13 GHz &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

So, how to make the drawing (or say the draft)? Thanks in advance!

Is this what you want ? The output:

I use nicematrix plus some tikz code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c|cccccc|}[hlines]
    \Block{2-1}{\diagbox{A}{C}} & \Block{1-3}{A} &      &      & B & C & D \\
                                & A1             & A2   & A3   &   &   &   \\
    3600A                       &                & x(W) & x(W) &   &   &   \\
    HRX 50-100 keV              &                & 1(W) & 1(W) &   &   &   \\
    HRX 32-50 keV               &                & 1(W) & 1(W) &   &   &   \\
    HRX 15-25 keV               &                &      &      &   &   &   \\
    1-8A                        &                &      &      &   &   &   \\
    1-200A                      &                &      &      &   &   &   \\
    1-800A                      &                &      &      &   &   &   \\
    13 GHz                      &                &      &      &   &   &   \\
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]
      \draw (1.1) -- (2.2);
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]
      \node[below left] at (2.2) {B};
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


WOW! It's so cool! This is what I want! Thanks a lot!
I can reproduce this Table in an {article} documentclass.
But, I'm writing my manuscript and I need to make this table in the documentclass[linenumbers,preprint]{aastex63}. Your code will produce some bugs, e.g. the reference, sections and figures can't be cited.

Here are the bugs:
LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab1' on page 4 undefined on input line 191.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig2' on page 4 undefined on input line 192.
./ms.tex:244: Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token ([): `c' used.
See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...
l.244     \Block{2-1}{\diagbox{A}{C}} &
\Block{1-3}{A} &      &      & B & C...

@DCSONG You should check the manual of nicematrix carefully, whic says that
"In order to use nicematrix with the class aastex631 (of the American Astronomical Society), you have to add the following lines in the preamble of your document :"
\BeforeBegin{NiceTabular}{\let\begin\BeginEnvironment\let\end\EndEnvironment}
\BeforeBegin{NiceArray}{\let\begin\BeginEnvironment}
\BeforeBegin{NiceMatrix}{\let\begin\BeginEnvironment}

Then everything will works right.

OK! Thanks for your suggestion~ :D @zpding

@DCSONG If your problem was solved, you can accept this answer.
